# How to change element's class depending on it's content?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-template

I have an Angular 2 project, where I want to change an element's class depending on it's content. So, I have a template with `<span>{{item}}</span>` element, and a *.css* file with multiple styles, depending on element's class. What i want to do is, changing `<span>`'s class depending on which value `{{item}}` has.
For example if `item=2` than it's class will be equal to `c1`, but if `item`'s value changes to 4 then it will have `class = "c2"`.

Comment: A switch function to define the classes based on each case?

Comment: Yes, how this can be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<span class="c{{(item/2)|number}}">{{item}}</span>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use if else statements for each case or switch functions with each case.

```js
if(item === '2') {
  return <span class="c1">{{item}}</span>
} else if(item === '4') {
  return <span class="c2">{{item}}</span>
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```